# jarに含ませたjsファイルを参照する方法

Tags: javascript, html5, spring-boot, jar

jarファイル内にJSファイルを含ませた場合、
そのjarファイルを参照させたプロジェクトからJS処理は実行可能なのでしょうか？
こちらのサイトを参考に簡単なプロジェクトをjar化してみました。
ttp://blog.livedoor.jp/morituri/archives/54648406.html#54648406-h1-jar
jarファイルを別のプロジェクトで参照させ、jar内のJavaクラスを利用できることは確認できました。

そこで、jarを作るプロジェクトのresourcesディレクトリの配下に適当にディレクトリを作り、jsファイルを用意してみました。
jarファイルを作成することはでき、別のプロジェクトから参照させるようにすると、参照ライブラリーとして、
そのjsファイルが見えることは確認できたのですが、
それをHTML5から利用する場合どのようにしていいのかわからずに困っています。
そもそも可能ではないのでしょうか？

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: springについて知識を持っていないので的確に回答できないのですが、「静的リソース(静的コンテンツ)へのアクセス」といったキーワードで検索すると、求められている情報が得られそうに思いますが、どうでしょう。

Comment: http://blog.livedoor.jp/morituri/archives/54648406.html#54648406-h1-jarを参考に可能であることが確認できました。たすかりました！

Comment: @kanko 問題が解決した場合には、 [自己回答](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1747/754) をしていただけますでしょうか。将来同じ問題に当たった人にとっての参考になります。